# Accept any data type (int, float, string) from user in any order

Tags: java

What should be the syntax to get StdInput and StdOutput in Java.

I need to take input from user, which could be in any order and any data type (int, float, string). My code takes so, but it does not allow the flexibility to accept data types in random order.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
double y = sc.nextDouble();
sc.nextLine();
String s = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("Double: " + y);
System.out.println("Int: " + x);
```

How do I get the input in any order irrespective of the data type?

Comment: Sample Input:

1
38.3
Hello
-8

Comment: Just use `String` type for all your inputs

Comment: @IvanPronin I am not sure, how many entries user will make. How about that?

Comment: @Shabbir - We need more information, what are you planning to do with the ints/doubles, certain calculations? If you're going to just store them, then as Ivan said, just use Strings.

Comment: I am working on creating a program that takes input from user, the input can be of any data type. 
Depending on the data type, tasks will be performed.

For example:

Sample Input:
10
Perfect
96.3
-8

The task would be like: add 1 to int, reverse if string
Sample Output: 
11
tcefreP
97.3
-7

Comment: save it to `String` and parse it

Comment: @Shabbir this may not be the smart way, but for fast and easy I would make every inputs `String`, then go thru each inputs and convert it to appropriate outputs. I hope that may help.

Comment: Half of the problem is solved: Using string data type to nullify rest.

The other half of the problem is, I am not sure how many input(s) will be provided.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want with the input.

But one thing you can do, is take the input as a string and then inspect the contents of the string. For example, you can trail and error on the datatype using the `parseInt()` and `parseDouble()` methods. Something like this:

```
try {
    // Try to parse it as an integer
    Integer.parseInt(input);
}
catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
    try {
        // Try to parse it as a double
        Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
    catch (NumberformatException exc) {
        // Else, it's a string
    }
}
```

However, below a more elegant way:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) { // Some condition
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("int: " + i);
    }
    else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("double: " + d);
    }
    else {
        String s = sc.next();
        System.out.println("string: " + s);
    }
}
```

*Note that the decimal separator is locale-dependent.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the type of the data from an arbitrary type, your only option (when using a Scanner) is to use `nextLine()` (or `next()`). These methods return a String which you can parse to the datatype you want, for example:

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
// For an integer
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
// For a double
double i = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Comment: That may have a problem, what if the inputs are strings or smiley faces? I may want to wrap it with `try and catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` has methods like `hasNextInt` and `hasNextDouble` to determine what type the next token is, so you can branch based on that:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    } else {
        String s = sc.next();
        if (s.equals("END")) break; // stop condition
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter(" ");
while(in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.next();
    try {
        Double d = Double.valueOf(s);
        d += 1;
        System.out.print(d);
        System.out.print(" ");
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        sb.reverse();
        System.out.print(sb.toString() + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, how would I get out of the loop?

Should I be using something like: Scanner.close();

Comment: It will just get out of the loop when the input ends. No need to use .close() method, you can use it though before the end of your program. because of the while condition in.hasNext()